# Creating Editable Lists Using HTML and JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, html-lists

I am trying to create an editable list in HTML and JQuery. 
The list should get appended whenever the user enters value in the form and hits submit form button.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="container">

    <!-- the to-do list -->
    <div class="column">
        <ul id="todo-list" contenteditable="true">
            <li>Item #1 <a href="#" class="todo-list-remove">remove</a></li>
            <li>Item #2 <a href="#" class="todo-list-remove">remove</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <!-- form to add an item to the list -->
    <div class="column">
        <form id="todo-form" action="#" method="post">
            <label>Add an item</label><br/>
            <input class= "target" name="todo-form-add" id="todo-form-add1" type="text" placeholder="New item">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnName" onclick="add_button()">

        </form> 
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is the JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var list = $('#todo-list').val();
});
$("#btnName").click(function(){

      $("#todo-list").append("<li>Message Center<a href='#' class='todo-list-remove'>remove</a></li>");

      $("#todo-list li:last").hide();
      $("#todo-list li:last").fadeIn();

});
```

My JS Fiddle handle is at:
http://jsfiddle.net/aD9dr/

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a disconnect between your markup and script. What you can do is bind your event trigger in your script piece.

```
$(function() {
    $('#btnName').on('click', function() {
        add_item();    
    });
});
```

Also, be sure that you're targeting the right tag. You were targeting `$('todo-list.ul')` which, in markup, would be `<todo-list class="ul"></todo-list>` which is not a valid tag :)

[Updated Fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/aD9dr/4/)

Answer (score 0):

To add up to Chad's answer, try removing the form and changing

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnName" onclick="add_button()">
```

for

```
<button id="btnName" onclick="add_button()">Submit</button>
```

I think you need to post to the server in order to accomplish what you want to do so a form POST seems pretty useless.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed some lines in jquery to get the value which is typed in input box so when it get submitted you will get the value and remove

```
<div id="container">
<div class="column">
  <ul id="todo-list">
    <li>Item #1 <a href="#" class="todo-list-remove">remove</a>
    </li>
    <li>Item #2 <a href="#" class="todo-list-remove">remove</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
  <div class="column">
    <form id="todo-form" action="#" method="POST">
      <label>Add an item</label>
      <br />
      <input class="target" name="todo-form-add" id="todo-form-add" type="text" placeholder="New item" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnName" />
    </form>
  </div>
```

```
function add_item() {
    var a = $('#todo-form-add').val() ;
    $('ul#todo-list').append(`<li>`+ a +`<a href='#' class='todo-list-remove' > 
     remove </a></li>`);
    event.preventDefault();
}

$(function() {
    $('#btnName').on('click', function() {
        add_item();
    });
});
```

Hope your problem will get solved from this !